# At the moment when I click on keyboard letter, it appears in EditText1, next letter in EditText2

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have TableLayout with few rows and in the last TableRow i created five columns with EditText inside. Each editText have an id(et1, et2, et3, et4, et5).
I want my app to work like this: When I push a character in keyboard it appears instantly in et1, next letter appears on et2 and so on till et5.
Is that possible? If yes, then how?

I've made my app to show on-screen keyboard and now I'm stuck. I'm a rookie in android programming, Help, guys!

Answer (score 1):

Set a counter at Action_down event tracking function. If counter is 1, then set it like

editText1.setText("keypressed");

if counter is 2 then,

editText2.setText("keypressed");

etc..

Sice we can add strings dynamically to editText this must work! have a try dude!